# Split a list of strings by comma

Tags: python, string, list

I want to convert

```
['60,78', '70,77', '80,74', '90,75', '100,74', '110,75']
```

in to

```
['60', '78', '70', '77'.. etc]
```

I thought I could use

```
for word in lines:
    word = word.split(",")
    newlist.append(word)
return newlist
```

but this produces this instead:

```
[['60', '78'], ['70', '77'], ['80', '74'], ['90', '75'], ['100', '74'], ['110', '75']]
```

Can anyone please offer a solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) instead of `list.append`.

```
newlist = []
for word in lines:
    word = word.split(",")
    newlist.extend(word)  # <----
return newlist
```

Or, using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = ['60,78', '70,77', '80,74', '90,75', '100,74', '110,75']
>>> [x for xs in lst for x in xs.split(',')]
['60', '78', '70', '77', '80', '74', '90', '75', '100', '74', '110', '75']
```

Answer (score 6):

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) actually returns a list.

> Return a list of the words in the string, using *sep* as the delimiter string.

Since you are appending the returned list to `newlist`, you are getting a list of lists. Instead use `list.extend` method, like this

```
for word in lines:
    newlist.extend(word.split(","))
```

But you can simply use nested list comprehension like this

```
>>> data = ['60,78', '70,77', '80,74', '90,75', '100,74', '110,75']
>>> [item for items in data for item in items.split(",")]
['60', '78', '70', '77', '80', '74', '90', '75', '100', '74', '110', '75']
```

Answer (score 1):

using [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) :

```
from itertools import chain

print(list(chain.from_iterable(ele.split(",") for ele in l)))
['60', '78', '70', '77', '80', '74', '90', '75', '100', '74', '110', '75']
```

The more items you have to flatten chain does it  a bit more efficiently:

```
In [1]: l= ["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20" for _ in range(100000)]

In [2]: from itertools import chain

In [3]: l= ["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30" for _ in range(10000)]

In [4]: timeit (list(chain.from_iterable(ele.split(",") for ele in l)))
100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop

In [5]: timeit  [item for items in l for item in items.split(",")]
10 loops, best of 3: 20.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this was the easiest way (thanks to a friend who helped with this)

```
list=['60,78', '70,77', '80,74', '90,75', '100,74', '110,75']
for word in list:
    chapter, number = word.split(',') #word = word.split(',')
    print(word)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't produce the expected output.