# How to remove special character in a list of string and split it into separate elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of string like this:

```
list = ["A", "B", "C", "E", "0,2344 | 0,234 | 0,2345 | 0,265 | 0.2235 |"]
```

Output expected shoud be:

```
list = ["A", "B", "C", "E", "0,2344", "0,234", "0,2345", "0,265", "0.2235"]
```

Can anyone suggest me some ways to do this?

Comment: Which special characters can be part of your list elements?

Comment: I want to remove | character in the last element of list 1 and split last element of list 1 into last 5 elements of list 2

Comment: no, it only contains ` | `

Comment: @JiroAkira : Pls change your `list` name from `list` to something else such as `list1`, do not use **built-in** `keywords` as variable names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a list of strings by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886794/split-a-list-of-strings-by-comma) You can adapt solutions from this post by replacing the comma separator by `"|"` and stripping unnecessary spaces.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood from the comment. You can try this.

```
list_a=[j.strip() for i in list_a for j in i.split('|')]
```

Unrelated to the question: *Don't use built-in / keywords name as variable names.*

Answer (score 1):

you need:

```
new_list = []
for l in list1:
    y = l.split("|") 
    new_list.extend([j.strip() for j in y if j])

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', '0,2344', '0,234', '0,2345', '0,265', '0.2235']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this,

```
lst = ["A", "B", "C", "E", "0,2344 | 0,234 | 0,2345 | 0,265 | 0.2235 |"]

output = []
for item in lst:
    if item.find("|"):
        values = item.replace("|", "").strip().split()
        for value in values:
            output.append(value.strip())
    else:
        output.append(item)

print(output)
```

**Or better** you could use **list comprehension** like this,

```
lst =[subitem.strip() for item in lst for subitem in item.split('|') if subitem]
print(lst)
```

And output will be,

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', '0,2344', '0,234', '0,2345', '0,265', '0.2235']
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
ans= ''.join(i for i in '["A", "B", "C", "E", "0,2344 | 0,234 | 0,2345 | 0,265 | 0.2235 |"]'. replace('|','","'));
ans= ''.join(i for i in ans. replace(',""',''))
print(ans.replace(' ',''))
```

above code gives expected output as written below.

```
["A","B","C","E","0,2344","0,234","0,2345","0,265","0.2235"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do as follows:

```
   list = ["A", "B", "C", "E", "0,2344 | 0,234 | 0,2345 | 0,265 | 0.2235 |"]

   new_list = new_list = [ch.strip() for word in list for ch in word.split('|')]
   new_list.remove('')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to remove | character in the last element of list 1 and split last element of list 1 into last 5 elements of list 2
```

try this

```
result = list[0:-1]+list[-1].replace(' ', '').strip('|').split('|')
```